# Let $P(X=1)=0.6$ and $P(X=1,Y>=5)=0.2$. Find $P(X=1,Y<5)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm thinking with the given information $P(Y\geq5) = P(X=1,Y\geq5)/P(X=1)$, so $P(Y\geq5)=0.33$. Therefore, $P(Y<5) = 1-P(Y\geq5)$, so $P(Y<5)=0.67$. Which means $P(X=1,Y<5) = P(Y<5)P(X=1) = 0.402$.

Is this correct? If not, how is it done?

They are not independent.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to ask a single question and to engage with those that answer it before asking a series of questions. I'm sure that you would be better equipped to answer your second question if you spent time engaged with you first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the set of all $x, y$ values such that $X = 1$.  Let $B$ denote the set of all $x, y$ values such that $X = 1, Y \geq 5$.  Let $C$ denote the set of all $x, y$ values such that $X = 1, Y < 5$.  Then, we have $A = B \cup C$ and $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, i.e., they do not overlap.  Therefore,

$$P(A) = P(B) + P(C)$$

This is a general principle you should make sure you remember and understand.  Spelling out what $A, B, C$ mean, we have:

$$P(X = 1) = P(X=1, Y \geq 5) + P(X = 1, Y < 5)$$

Independence has nothing to do with this problem, and finding $P(Y \geq 5)$ is not applicable and not possible with the given information.  The only pairs of $x, y$ we have any information about are those where $x = 1$, so we can not possibly say anything about $Y$ in general.